# Building 64bit Python in Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, 64-bit, building

I am trying to automate the build 64bit Python-2.7.6 for our project. The default Python MSI uses an older version of OpenSSL which we want to upgrade. I am totally new to building applications under Windows. All the documentation I found are about opening it in an IDE and then building Python pulling all its dependencies. Is there anyway this process could be automated from the command line. What should one do build it for 64bit Windows. Inside the PCbuild directory there are only visual studio project files. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
I did some search and found a build.bat in the PCbuild directory. I am trying to replicate what it does, by setting the path variables for Release|x64. However when I do that and execute it still tries to build make_versioninfo, make_buildinfo as "Release|Win32" instead of "Release|x64" this causes these two initial builds to break with the following error:

```
fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'
```

There other errors that I need to resolve, I was hoping to tackle the initial errors hoping that may be those errors are related to why my build is failing later. Also, I was hoping if someone could suggest how can I set the location of things like openssl so that build process finds them.